# Home siding blown off by strong wind. Wood and housewrap exposed

Tags: exterior, house-wrap, house

The vinyl siding on one side of my house has been blown off by strong wind. The housewrap and wood have been exposed.

Could I leave it exposed like this under rain or snow? I am not sure what material they are made and if they are waterproofed. If not, is there any temporary fix I could apply before a contractor comes and repairs it?
Here is a picture.
[image]

Comment: I would go the blue tarp route, especially if you're not sure how long it will take to get the siding repaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builders leave the entire building in this state for months.  The tyvek is generally recommended to be covered within 6 months for uv issues.  As is it should shed water and you have a rainscreen gap.  Get it fixed when you can but I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: The tyvek seems to be torn at least at bottom left, and there is clearly ice and snow on the building. I'd worry about water getting inside the walls of the lower story below.

Comment: It does look torn in the lower left.  So that part should at least be tapped and stapled back down to the sheathing.  The tyvek / flashing should be installed shingle style with the upper pieces overlapping the lower pieces such that if water gets on the top piece it can't get under the lower piece.

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of vinyl siding in this case apart from aesthetics? Is it supposed to protect the tyvek?

Comment: The siding in this case vinyl siding is supposed to protect the tyvek from UV.  It also prevents the majority of liquid water and to some extend wind driven air leaks from entering your building.  It also prevents, in cooperation with bug screen, bugs from getting into the sheathing area.  The last thing siding is doing in your case is providing a drainage plane and drying potential via the rain screen - it is hard for their to be drying potential if the rain screen area continually gets wet.

Answer (score 3):

That tyvek is the vapour barrier, it won’t let rain through… As long as it has been installed correctly…

But if they failed to install the siding correctly then who knows.

Sooner it is covered the better.